# how to make <display:table> scrollable?

Tags: html, css, jsp, struts, displaytag

I am using `<display:table>` tag to display table in jsp page.

now i can navigate records using page numbers.

Now i want display all records in single page but with scrolling.(no pagination)

this table is set as a part of page so like only one div can be scrollable.rest of page should be as it is.

Please suggest..!

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle ??

Comment: sorry.. i can not add, it's too big.

Comment: can you provide the url of website ?

Comment: What part do you want to scroll? The whole table or just the records with a static header row?

Comment: Once observe the Naveen's solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159696/scroll-bar-for-display-table

Comment: @sureshmanda Neveen's solution, if you look a little closer, it is a `question to his own question`, and not a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try to put your table in the `div` tag then edit the css file:

```
<div class="displayTableFrame" style="margin-top: 20px; padding-top: 30px;">            
    <display:table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" name="myList" class="dataTable">             
        <display:column class="colId" property="id" title="ID" />    
        <display:column class="colName" property="name" />    
        <display:column class="colEmail" property="email" />    
        <display:column class="colStatus" property="status" />    
        <display:column class="colComments" property="description" title="Comments" />                                                                            
    </display:table>    
</div>
```

For example, the `div` tag is `displayTableFrame`. Then css:

```
.displayTableFrame {
    background-color: green;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 320px
    width: 100%;
}
```

give it a fixed heigth then overflow-x: scroll.
Try and let us know.

**Update:**

Thanks to Jaimon and his magical codes, the solution for fixed header can be found here:

[Jaimon's Blog](http://jaimonmathew.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/making-scrollable-tables-with-fixed-headers-updated-2/)

I have tested and it works smoothly with IE8 and FF14.

Good luck Ruchi!

Best regards,

Khanh Tran

Comment: this is right code for make table scrollable..but what i want is need to stick header and make records scrollable only not whole table.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this!!!

```
$(document).ready(
        function()  {
            scrolify($('#idOfDisplayTable'), 100); // 100 = HEIGHT
        }
    );

    function scrolify(tblAsJQueryObject, height){
        var oTbl = tblAsJQueryObject;
        var oTblDiv = $("<div/>");
        oTblDiv.css('height', height);
        oTblDiv.css('overflow-y','scroll');             
        oTbl.wrap(oTblDiv);

        // save original width
        oTbl.attr("data-item-original-width", oTbl.width());
        oTbl.find('thead tr td').each(function(){
            $(this).attr("data-item-original-width",$(this).width());
        }); 
        oTbl.find('tbody tr:eq(0) td').each(function(){
            $(this).attr("data-item-original-width",$(this).width());
        });                 


        // clone the original table
        var newTbl = oTbl.clone();
        oTbl.parent().parent().prepend(newTbl);
        newTbl.wrap("<div/>");

        // remove table header from original table
        oTbl.find('thead tr').remove();                 
        // remove table body from new table
        newTbl.find('tbody tr').remove();   

        // replace ORIGINAL COLUMN width                
        newTbl.width(newTbl.attr('data-item-original-width'));
        newTbl.find('thead tr td').each(function(){
            $(this).width($(this).attr("data-item-original-width"));
        });     
        oTbl.width(oTbl.attr('data-item-original-width'));      
        oTbl.find('tbody tr:eq(0) td').each(function(){
            $(this).width($(this).attr("data-item-original-width"));
        });                 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sweety 
As I have answered to vary similar question already, I am going to pass you the example I have made for that answer.

The main thing is for you to define `div` outside table data. Something like this:

```
 <table>
        <tr><td>
            <div id="tbl-container" style="width: 850px;">
               <display:table name="CustomerList" export="true" id="customerList" class="dataTable" defaultorder="ascending" cellspacing="1" requestURI="" frame="true" decorator="org.displaytag.decorator.TotalTableDecorator"> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="OverallOverdue.pdf" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="OverallOverdue.xls" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="true" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="OverallOverdue.csv" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="true" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="OverallOverdue.xml" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement">top</display:setProperty> 
                 .........  
                 </display:table></div> </td></tr>
             <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
             <tr><td>

             </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<div id="export-links"> 
  This is not scroll-able. It will stay in position
</div>
```

Then you could position the `div` and do with it separately from the table (or any other div, as a matter of a fact)

You can just try and see how this is working on a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LQJY5/2/

Comment: Mr.Aleks once observe, on which date i asked my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159696/scroll-bar-for-display-table/15175576) and on which date i answered here. But what my problem is explained there....

Comment: @sureshmanda If you know it is closely to copy-paste, you must a have seen the sentence `"I am going to pass you the example I have made for that answer"` But I am just guessing that you have actually read the answers

Comment: I am starting to believe this is duplicate of account of Neven, you write all the same sentences, even the number of the dots are the same = 4 ;)

Comment: @Aleks we both r working in same org. i am also facing same problem.

Comment: @sureshmanda so, if you are having the same problem, how come you both haven't tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Place it in your JSP Javascript code

```
if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
{
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/pages/styles/locked-column.css" />');
}
else
{
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/pages/styles/displaytagex.css" />');
}
```

and make a locked-column.css class as

```
div#tbl-container {
width: 400px;
/ default value will be overrided by minimum of table width or screen resolution/
height: 300px;
overflow: auto;
/
scrollbar-base-color: #ffeaff;

/
}
.dataTable { /table-layout: fixed; /
border-collapse: collapse;
/ background-color: WhiteSmoke; /
}
.dataTable th {
top: expression(document . getElementById("tbl-container") . scrollTop-2
); / IE5+ only /
z-index: 20;
font-size: small;
padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
cursor: default;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: small;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgb(46, 54, 64);
color: #FFFFF;
}
.dataTable thead tr {
position: relative;
height: 10px;
background-color: #7CA4E0;
}
.dataTable th a:link,th a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
}
.dataTable a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
.dataTable thead th.sorted A {
font-weight: bolder;
}
.dataTable td {
padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important;
}
.dataTable tbody tr {
height: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.dataTable tbody tr.odd {
background-color: #eee;
font-size: x-small;
}
.dataTable tbody tr.tableRowEven,tr.even {
background-color: #ddd
font-size: x-small;
}
.dataTable tbody tr td:last-child { / padding-right: 20px; /
}
/these styles have nothing to do with the locked column/
.dataTable body {
background-color: white;
color: black;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
.dataTable tbody td {
padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px !important;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: x-small;
}
.exportlinks {
font-family: sans-serif;
}
/ style sheet to display light blue color for a mouse on row over event /
.dataTable tr.rowMouseOver {
color: white;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color: rgb(228, 59, 47); /#8888FF;/
}
.dataTable .order1 {
background-position: right 50%;
background-image: url('../Images/arrow_up.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-weight: bold;
}
.dataTable .order2 {
background-position: right 50%;
background-image: url('../Images/arrow_down.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-weight: bold;
}
span.export {
padding: 0 4px 1px 20px;
font-size: x-small;
text-align: center;
}
span.excel {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_excel.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.csv {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_csv.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.xml {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_xml.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.first {
background-image: url('../Images/first.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.last {
background-image: url('../Images/last.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.pdf {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_pdf.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.rtf {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_rtf.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
.rightAlignedPadded {
text-align: right;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

and antoher css as displaytagex.css, contains

```
input.displayTableFirst {
background-image: url('../Images/first.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 0px;
width: 27px;
height: 24px;
}
input.displayTableNext {
background-image: url(../Images/next.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 0px;
width: 27px;
height: 24px;
border: 10px;
}
input.displayTablePrevious {
background-image: url(../Images/previous.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 0px;
width: 27px;
height: 24px;
border: 10px;
}
input.displayTableLast {
background-image: url(../Images/last.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 0px;
width: 27px;
height: 24px;
border: 10px;
}
.displayPageButtonSimple {
background: #AEAFAD;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: small;
color: black;
}
.displayPageButton {
background: #AEAFAD;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: small;
width: 70px;
color: black;
}
overlay {
background-image: url(../Images/blackDot.png);
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.displayTableFrame {
background-color: white;
height: 320px;
width: 100%;
}
.dataTable {
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
/
width: 98%; /
}
.dataTable th {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: small;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important;
background-color: rgb(46, 54, 64);
color: #FFFFF;
}
.dataTable td {
padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important;
}
.dataTable thead tr {
position: relative;
height: 10px;
}
.dataTable th a:link,th a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
}
.dataTable a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
.dataTable thead th.sorted A {
font-weight: bolder;
}
.dataTable tbody {
width: 400px;
height: 230px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}
.dataTable tbody tr {
height: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.dataTable tbody tr.odd {
background-color: #eee
}
.dataTable tbody tr.tableRowEven,tr.even {
background-color: #ddd
}
.dataTable tbody tr td:last-child {
padding-right: 20px;
}
.dataTable tbody td {
padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px !important;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: small;
}
.exportlinks {
font-family: sans-serif;
}
/ style sheet to display light blue color for a mouse on row over event /
.dataTable tr.rowMouseOver {
color: white;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color: rgb(228, 59, 47); / #7CA4E0; /
}
.dataTable .order1 {
background-position: right 50%;
background-image: url('../Images/arrow_up.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-weight: bold;
}
.dataTable .order2 {
background-position: right 50%;
background-image: url('../Images/arrow_down.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-weight: bold;
}
.defaultDataTable {
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #000066;
font-size: xx-small;
margin: 5px;
font: bold normal normal xx-small "Arial Black";
}
.defaultDataTable th {
border-right: 1px solid #c8c8ff;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 12px;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
background-color: #AEAFAD;
margin-right: 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.defaultDataTable td {
font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
padding-left: 2px;
}
.defaultDataTable tr.total td {
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: top;
font-weight: bold;
border-top: 1px solid black;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.defaultDataTable tr.total td.customer {
visibility: hidden;
}
.defaultDataTable td.hidden {
display: none;
}
.defaultDataTable th.hidden {
display: none;
}
.defaultDataTable th.r {
text-align: right;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.defaultDataTable th.c {
text-align: center;
}
.defaultDataTable td.r {
text-align: right;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.defaultDataTable td.c {
text-align: center;
}
.defaultDataTable tr.odd {
background-color: #eee
}
.defaultDataTable tr.even {
background-color: #ddd;
}
.defaultDataTable th a {
text-align: left;
color: black;
}
.defaultDataTable .order1 {
background-position: right 50%;
background-image: url('../Images/arrow_up.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat
}
.defaultDataTable .order2 {
background-position: right 50%;
background-image: url('../Images/arrow_down.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat
}
span.export {
padding: 0 4px 1px 20px;
font-size: x-small;
text-align: center;
}
span.excel {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_excel.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.csv {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_csv.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.xml {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_xml.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.first {
background-image: url('../Images/first.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.last {
background-image: url('../Images/last.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.pdf {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_pdf.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
span.rtf {
background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_rtf.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
}
.pageHeader {
height: 60px;
background-image: url('../Images/header.gif');
background-repeat: repeat-x
}
.pageHeaderText {
font-size: 30px;
margin-left: 5px;
color: black;
font-family: "century gothic", verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
display: inline;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.content {
width: 50%;
padding: 10px;
}
.rightColumn {
width: 3px;
}
.customer {
width: 10%;
text-align: left;
}
.company {
width: 10%;
text-align: left;
}
.email {
width: 14%;
text-align: left;
}
.broker {
width: 10%;
text-align: right;
}
.company {
width: 10%;
text-align: left;
}
.fmv {
width: 13%;
text-align: left;
}
.country {
width: 12%;
text-align: left;
}
.tax {
width: 14%;
text-align: left;
}
.size9 {
width: 9%;
text-align: left;
}
.hideColumn {
display: none;
}
.so {
width: 10%;
text-align: left;
}
.type {
width: 10%;
text-align: left;
}
.fmv {
width: 20%;
text-align: left;
}
.plan {
width: 13%;
text-align: left;
}
.eid {
width: 15%;
text-align: left;
}
.orderNumber {
width: 10%;
text-align: left;
}
.orderDate {
text-align: left;
width: 14%;
}
.productName {
width: 25%;
}
.size35 {
width: 35%;
text-align: left;
}
.quantity {
text-align: center;
width: 10%;
}
.rightAlignedPadded {
text-align: right;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.logo {
border-top: 1px solid #000066;
border-left: 1px solid #000066;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000066;
display: inline;
text-align: right;
}
.code {
font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, "courier new", monospace;
font-size: xx-small;
}
.borderedInline {
display: inline;
border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
border: 0px;
}
.pagelinks {
color: #999999;
margin: 5px;
}
.pagelinks img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and make a jsp like

```
<div id="tbl-container">
   <display:table name="sessionScope.participantList" export="true" id="tmpId" class="dataTable" defaultorder="ascending" cellspacing="1" > 
   <display:setProperty name="decorator.media.html" value="displaytag.sample.decorators.MyHtmlTotalWrapper" /> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.decorator" value="displaytag.sample.decorators.MyITextTotalWrapper" /> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="ParticipantProfile.pdf" 
/> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.rtf.decorator" value="displaytag.sample.decorators.MyITextTotalWrapper" /> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.rtf.filename" value="ParticipantProfile.rtf" 
/> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="ParticipantProfile.xls" 
/> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="true" /> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="ParticipantProfile.csv" 
/> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="true" /> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="ParticipantProfile.xml" 
/> 
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement">top</display:setProperty> 
    <display:column title="" > 
    </display:column> 

    </display:table></div> 
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
    <div id="export-links"> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Omg, this is the very same question you Naveen asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159696/scroll-bar-for-display-table/15175576 , and you asked for an answer, and , like in that question, your answer to this question is **completely** **wrong**

Comment: @Aleks : But, there i explained my code and what i am getting my problem is exports are placed in scrollable table. How to make it constant?

Comment: Mr.Aleks once observe, on which date i asked my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159696/scroll-bar-for-display-table/15175576) and on which date i answered here. But what my problem is explained there....

Comment: You asked on 1. March , and you answered here on 2. March. And I agree your problem is explained there, and there is also a possible solution also posted there. So I am not posing any more comments here, as this is separate question.