# Scroll bar for display table

Tags: scroll, struts, displaytag

I was wondering how to insert a `<DIV>` tag in between the pagination bar
and the actual `TABLE` that starts the results display if I have the
pagination bar at the top. If I just put the `<DIV>` tag right before my
display:table, it also includes the pagination stuff inside the scroll bar.

Also, I cannot figure out how to set the style to `TBODY` as it is a little bit
confusing. I am not sure if you guys wrote this stuff but can you advise me
if you have any idea how to achieve this.
 and my code is

```
<display:table id="data1" name="invprbmList" requestURI=""  pagesize="10" export="true" style="width:100%;" decorator="org.displaytag.decorator.TotalTableDecorator">
  <tr><td><display:setProperty name="paging.banner.item_name">Invoice</display:setProperty>
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.items_name">Invoices</display:setProperty>
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.some_items_found"><span class="pagebanner"> {0} Invoices found, displaying {2} to {3}. </span></display:setProperty>           
    <bean:define id="invoiceNo"><bean:write name="data1" property="invoiceNo"/></bean:define>
    <bean:define id="notes"><bean:write name="data1" property="notes"/></bean:define>
    <bean:define id="strFlag"><bean:write name="data1" property="strFlag"></bean:write></bean:define>

    <display:column  title="Invoice No." sortable="true" property="invoiceNo" media="xml csv pdf excel" class="l" headerClass="hl" />
    <display:column  property="invDate" title="Invoice Date" format="{0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}" sortable="true" class="l" headerClass="hl"/>
    <display:column  media="html" title="Amount" property="invAmount" format="<%=strDispCurrency %>" sortable="true" class="r" headerClass="hr" />
    <display:column  title="Amount" sortable="true" property="invAmount" media="xml csv pdf excel" class="r" headerClass="hr" />
    <display:column  property="dueDate"     title="Due Date" format="{0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}" sortable="true" class="l" headerClass="hl"/>
    <display:column  media="html" title="Balance" property="balance" format="<%=strDispCurrency %>" sortable="true" class="r" headerClass="hr" />
    <display:column  title="Balance" sortable="true" property="balance" media="xml csv pdf excel" class="r" headerClass="hr" />
    <display:column  title="Notes" sortable="true" property="notes"  media="xml csv pdf excel"  class="c" headerClass="hc"/>                                                  
    <display:column  property="invPoNum" title="P.O. No." sortable="true"  class="l" headerClass="hl"/>
    <display:column  property="invRefNo" title="Ref. No." sortable="true"  class="lbr" headerClass="hlbr"/>
    <display:column  property="status" title="Status" sortable="true" class="l" headerClass="hl"/>                              
  </td></tr>
</display:table>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the example that you are discussing?

Comment: Without the link nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Having the code will help.

Comment: @NaveenKumar please select answer if somebody answered the question. It seems to me it that you have set bounty, and answered to your self. And put up votes to 4, for your answer to be selected. Don't use developers time in-vain.

Comment: same problem occured Mr. Aleks... Nthng is change there. I am trying it....

Comment: Have you looked at http://jsfiddle.net/LQJY5/1/ , which I have created? You can try to scroll down the table, and you can see the `div` is staying in place

Comment: Ok, tried, and what is not is not working correctly in the code I have put?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `CSS` class `locked-column.css` as:

```
div#tbl-container { 
        width: 740px; 
        /* default value will be overrided by minimum of table width or screen 
resolution*/ 
        height: 300px; 
        margin-top: -11px;
        overflow: auto; 
        /* 
                scrollbar-base-color: #ffeaff; 
        */ 
} 

.dataTable { /*table-layout: fixed; */ 
        border-collapse: collapse; 
        /* background-color: WhiteSmoke; */ 
} 

.dataTable th { 
        top: expression(document . getElementById("tbl-container") . scrollTop-2 
                ); /* IE5+ only */ 
        z-index: 20; 
        font-size: small; 
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important; 
        text-align: center;
        position: relative; 
        cursor: default; 
        font-family: sans-serif; 
        font-size: small; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        background-color: #BBCCFF;
        color: #FFFFF; 
} 

.dataTable thead tr { 
        position: relative; 
        height: 10px; 
        /*background-color: #7CA4E0;*/ 
} 

.dataTable th a:link,th a:visited { 
        color: #1155cc;
        font-weight: bold; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        font-family: sans-serif;
} 

.dataTable a:hover { 
        color: #1155cc;
        text-decoration: underline; 
        font-family: sans-serif; 
        font-weight: bold; 
} 

.dataTable thead  th.sorted A { 
        font-weight: bolder; 
} 

.dataTable td { 
        padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px !important; 
} 

.dataTable tbody tr { 
        height: auto; 
        white-space: nowrap; 
} 

.dataTable tbody tr.odd { 
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size:  x-small; 
} 

.dataTable tbody tr.tableRowEven,tr.even { 
        background-color: #DDE5FF;
        font-size:  x-small; 
} 

.dataTable tbody tr td:last-child { /* padding-right: 20px; */ 

} 

/*these styles have nothing to do with the locked column*/ 
.dataTable body { 
        background-color: white; 
        color: black; 
        font-family: sans-serif; 
} 

.dataTable tbody td { 
        padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px !important; 
        font-family: sans-serif; 
        font-size: x-small; 
} 

.exportlinks { 
        font-family: sans-serif; 
} 

/* style sheet to display light blue color for a mouse on row over event */ 
.dataTable tr.rowMouseOver { 
        color: white; 
        background-repeat: repeat-x; 
        background-color: rgb(228, 59, 47); /*#8888FF;*/ 
} 

.dataTable .order1 { 
        background-position: right 50%; 
        background-image: url('../Images/arrow_up.gif'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        font-weight: bold; 
} 

.dataTable .order2 { 
        background-position: right 50%; 
        background-image: url('../Images/arrow_down.gif'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        font-weight: bold; 
} 

span.export { 
        padding: 0 4px 1px 20px; 
        font-size: x-small; 
        text-align: center; 
} 

span.excel { 
        background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_excel.png'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        width: 16px; 
} 

span.csv { 
        background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_csv.png'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        width: 16px; 
} 

span.xml { 
        background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_xml.png'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        width: 16px; 
} 

span.first { 
        background-image: url('../Images/first.jpg'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        width: 16px; 
} 

span.last { 
        background-image: url('../Images/last.jpg'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        width: 16px; 
} 

span.pdf { 
        background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_pdf.png'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        width: 16px; 
} 

span.rtf { 
        background-image: url('../Images/ico_file_rtf.png'); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        width: 16px; 
} 

.rightAlignedPadded { 
        text-align: right; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
}
```

call this `CSS` class in your JSP's JavaScript:

```
if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') 
{ 
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/locked-column.css" />'); 
} 
else 
{ 
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/displaytag1.css" />'); 
}
```

and make your `display-tag` as:

```
      <table>
        <tr><td>
            <div id="tbl-container" style="width: 850px;">
               <display:table name="CustomerList" export="true" id="customerList" class="dataTable" defaultorder="ascending" cellspacing="1" requestURI="" frame="true" decorator="org.displaytag.decorator.TotalTableDecorator"> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="OverallOverdue.pdf" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="OverallOverdue.xls" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="true" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="OverallOverdue.csv" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="true" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="OverallOverdue.xml" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement">top</display:setProperty> 
                 .........  
                 </display:table></div> </td></tr>
             <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
             <tr><td>
                <div id="export-links"> 
                </div> 
             </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: this it the answer or the question?

Comment: Sorry Naveen, but could you please state your question again. You are saying that they are constant but included in scrollbar, and what do you want? Could you state more precisely? Also, I have tried your code, at is doesn't show anything.. just "'Top....'" . Please include displaytag1.css as not all of us use IE

Comment: My requirement is only on IE. so, thats why i include locked-column.css code on top of there....

Comment: This marked answer is **actually** a question - `In above my answered code the export of the display table is not fixed as a footer` .. `Export functions are constant at footer(But it is included in scrollbar). How can i do that?`

Comment: @Aleks see the question what i am actually ask(scrollbar for display table)? After i got my display table scrollbar solution, i have to found that exports are in scroll and asked hw can i fix it? For the above question it is solution. But there is footer problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is included in scrollable, put:

```
<div id="export-links"> 
                </div>
```

outside `<table>`

You can't have a non-scrollable element inside scrollable table. Maybe you could define that element as absolute position, and to make it like that, but I wouldn't recommend that.

With your code try like this:

```
  <table>
        <tr><td>
            <div id="tbl-container" style="width: 850px;">
               <display:table name="CustomerList" export="true" id="customerList" class="dataTable" defaultorder="ascending" cellspacing="1" requestURI="" frame="true" decorator="org.displaytag.decorator.TotalTableDecorator"> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="OverallOverdue.pdf" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="OverallOverdue.xls" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="true" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="OverallOverdue.csv" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="true" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="OverallOverdue.xml" /> 
                 <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement">top</display:setProperty> 
                 .........  
                 </display:table></div> </td></tr>
             <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
             <tr><td>

             </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<div id="export-links"> 
  your links here
</div>
```

That way it will `not be included` in table that are scrolled

Take a look at this example I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/LQJY5/

Answer (score 0):

download flexcroll.js and flexcrollstyles.css from http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar and include these files.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td width='100%'> Paging: </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div id='customscroll' class='flexcroll' style='height:300px;'>
     <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Your content</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```